# SQL insert, get inserted id and insert again

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I need to insert a row to 2 tables with matching ids. When inserting to groups table, the id is auto increased.

I want to insert a new row in 'groups' table, get the id from the inserted row and then use it to insert a new row to the 'users_in_groups' table.

What I have:

```
INSERT INTO groups (name, owner_id ) VALUES ('groupname1', 'userid1');
INSERT INTO users_in_groups (user_id, group_id) VALUES ('userid1', group_id_from_above);
```

I tried

```
INSERT INTO groups (name, owner_id ) OUTPUT Inserted.id VALUES ('group1', 'user1');
```

But I do not know how to make the 2 'insert' work on 1 query. Is it even possible?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? The `OUTPUT` syntax is SQL Server.

Comment: I am using MySQL. Is there an alternative to output?

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

```
INSERT INTO groups (name, owner_id ) VALUES ('groupname1', 'userid1');
INSERT INTO users_in_groups (user_id, group_id) VALUES ('userid1', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Comment: That gets the id of the current table to insert, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @WhiteHatMan: this inserts into `users_in_groups` the id generated when inserting into `groups` - which is how I understood your question.